# Proceed to specific Route when Dynamic link is called even the app is closed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

```
 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  NavigatorState get _navigator => _rootNavigatorKey.currentState!;

         BlocListener<AppDeepLinkBloc, AppDeepLinkState>(
                              listener: (contextLink, state) {
                            // Show appropriate page based on the parameters on dynamic links.
                            if (state.linkData == null) return;
            
                            if (state.type == DynamicLinkType.purchases) {
                             
                              _navigator.pushNamed(
                                RouteConstants.customerPurchase,
                              );
                            }
                          }),
```

This code is working when the app is open only
but when the app is closed it doesn't proceed anymore